# How to search in lucene where there is only a single token for a field

Tags: lucene

I am creating an index where the documents are only a single term.
I am indexing domain names, so the field "domain" would look like:

```
example.com
thisiscool.com
justtesting.org
cnn.com
```

I am creating my search terms etc. programatically, and because all my document field is just a single term, it appears as though my searches won't work as they are since there is only a single term and if I add multiple terms in a boolean query it will never find anything.

**How should I be searching given I have only a single term?  I want to make this as efficient as possible.**

```
Query term = new TermQuery("domain", "this")
Query term2 = new TermQuery("domain", "cool")

// add to boolean query
bq.add(term, Occur.MUST)
bq.add(term2, Occur.MUST)

indexSearcher.search(bq, 100)
```

I was expecting to get "thisiscool.com" back, but I get 0 hits.  My guess is because lucene can't break things down into tokens, so it will never find any document that has both tokens "this" and "cool".

How should I be searching given this scenerio?

Answer (score 1):

<s>Apply a wildcard to your search clause.</s>

```
Query term = new TermQuery("domain", "this*");
Query term2 = new TermQuery("domain", "cool*"); // *cool* won't work sadly
```

However, that might not work because the logic is going to result in a query like this, where the domain has to begin with "this" as well as "cool"

```
bq.add(term, Occur.MUST)
bq.add(term2, Occur.MUST)

=> +domain:this* +domain:cool*

Query term = new TermQuery("domain", "this*cool*");

=> +domain:this*cool* // probably gets hits
```

If you're using newer versions then you can use regular expressions in queries:
http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/util/automaton/RegExp.html

---

The above example isn't actually how you should do this. I tested it out, and it doesn't even really work. What you'll want to do is build specialized queries, such as `PrefixQuery`, `WildcardQuery`, or `RegexpQuery`.

Additionally, if you're not using `QueryParser` or something that takes an `Analyzer`, queries have to match exactly to what's in your index. If domain is a `TextField` it might have been lowercased or had something else happen to it, so you'll need to know that too.

I'd just use regex.

```
RegExp r = new RegExp("this.*cool");
Query q = new RegexpQuery(new Term("domain", r.toString()));
```

It can be slow, but if you don't prefix with `any char` it should be perfectly fine. I'm also not entirely sure how to ignore case with this, but that might be default.

Comment: I would suggest using a prefix query in combination with a boolean query in this case. Adding wildcards by yourself does not look like proper usage for me.

Comment: @dom you're right, I actually got a little bit confused here. I'll edit my answer.